# RecyclerView remove an item from another class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

How do I remove an item in a RecyclerView from another class? I want to avoid using static methods, because I end up creating a lot of them and it is a buggy process. Is there any other solutions?

I want to remove it from a BottomSheetFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Life Cycle](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/Life-Cycle) for that. All you got to do is create an interface for communication.

```
interface RemoveItemSignal{
    void onRemove();
}
```

Then register a listener.

```
Signal<RemoveItemSignal> signal = SignalBag.Inject(RemoveItemSignal.class);
signal.addListener(this); // Your listener that implements RemoveItemSignal
```

And from your fragment you can dispatch this signal like this:

```
Signal<RemoveItemSignal> signal = SignalBag.Inject(RemoveItemSignal.class);
signal.dispatcher.onRemove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read documentations [communicating with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)?
It suggests to create listener interface inside `BottomSheetFragment` that will be responsible for actions from it. Than your `activity` should implement this like this

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements BottomSheetFragment.OnActionSelectedListener{
...

public void onActionSelected(int position) {
    // The user did some action from the BottomSheetFragment
    // Do something here to remove item from the RecyclerView
}
}
```